# Concatenating multiple text files inside a directory (including sub directories)into a single file in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, file, concatenation

I have a script which runs hourly and i am storing failure data as follows:

```
2017/10/09/00/RetryFailure.txt
2017/10/09/01/RetryFailure.txt
2017/10/09/02/RetryFailure.txt ...
```

where 10 is the month, 09 is the day and 00,01,02 are hours. Now at the end of the day i want to concatenate all(24) RetryFailure.txt into one file say RetryFailure10.txt.

Can anyone tell me the command to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat 2017/10/*/RetryFailure.txt > concat_file
```

or more restrictive

```
cat 2017/10/{00..23}/RetryFailure.txt > concat_file
```

Comment: Same problem as it will create a single file not a file per date.

Comment: i was thinking to store like that but now i realize its fine for my use case.

Comment: it's one file by date, depending on concat_file whose choice is let to the user, what may be confusing is that there is no month (?) only year and day?

Comment: i am sorry for missing month, updated that and thanks Nahuel you saved my time :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `find` for aggregating all the files of same date:

```
find . -name 'RetryFailure.txt' -exec bash -c \
'IFS=/ read -ra arr <<< "$1"; cat "$1" >> "RetryFailure${arr[2]}.txt"' - {} \;
```

For better performance use a loop with process substitution:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
   IFS=/ read -ra arr <<< "$file"
   cat "$file" >> "RetryFailure${arr[2]}.txt"
done < <(find . -name 'RetryFailure.txt' -print0)
```

- Using `find` we find each `RetryFailure.txt` file
- Using `read -ra` and `IFS=/` we split each entry by `/` and populate a shell array
- 2nd element of array is data number
- Using `cat ...` command we redirect each file into a new file using `${arr[2]}`

Comment: what is arr? and also can you elaborate more ?

Comment: `arr` us shell array, that gets populated by `read -ra` command using `/` as field separator.

Comment: i found following solution quite simple and it worked, is there any problem with this solution? cat 2017/10/*/RetryFailure.txt > concat_file

Comment: Yes problem is that it doesn't meet your own requirements. You wanted to redirect to a file per date not a single file for all dates. That solution will redirect every `RetryFailure.txt` file into a single file? Are you changing your own requirements?

Comment: actually initially i was thinking to store like that but now i realize that i'll be mailing this file everyday and won't require it further, btw i also tried your solution and it also work perfectly.. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156273/discussion-between-keshav-taparia-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 0):

Short **`find`** + **`cat`** approach:

```
find . -type f -name RetryFailure.txt -exec cat {} + > RetryFailure_merged.txt
```